# Can I list 6+ years of unpaid work at my family's restaurant as work experience?

Tags: resume

I worked at my family's restaurant throughout my undergraduate year and three years after graduating from college. I didn't get paid. This is just how my family works. Is it okay to list it as work experience?

If someone did an employment check, would they be able see that I had no taxes filed from the work that I did at my family's restaurant? If so, they would think I am lying about working there?

Comment: You can list it as volunteer work experience.  That's effectively the truth, and experience is still experience as far as employers are concerned.

Comment: Technically it belongs under education not work history, but no one will seriously object to you calling it a job.

Comment: "This is just how my family works". Sounds to me like you performed work in return for benefits. Work.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri wait, why is it technically education? What... is the technical distinction here?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri OP mentioned two different things. Your undergraduate degree is education, but the work you did while obtaining the degree is work experience.

Comment: Companies don't do background checks normally until you've gone through their interview process, and they're pretty sure they want to hire you.  You should have opportunity before they do check to inform them it was unpaid due to it being a job for the family.

Comment: @Kai - I'd list it as "worked for family business", and hope the family doesn't say "he didn't work for us, because we didn't pay him!  Woo hoo!" if asked.  It's definitely work experience if he was performing work duties.  Depends on how well he gets along with the family, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

Sure it is. Working in the family business is always a valuable asset to put on a resume.

Comment: Hi and welcome to The Workplace.  Please consider fleshing out your answer.  In it's current form it would be more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's worth adding to your resume ***if you think it is suitable*** and relates to future jobs that you apply for. Personally, if I wanted to work in a kitchen as a chef, then yeah. It relates to the job and shows that you've worked in a similar environment in the past.

As for the not getting paid part, it depends where you are in the world as to the laws and legality of that really. Personally, helping a family member out is one thing, but *working there for six years is another*.

Any experience whether paid or not is a good thing. Future employers don't need to know what you were being paid whilst there although they might want to know. List it as work experience nonetheless. **It shows commitment and that you can give your time to help in anyway you can**. Plus gaps in employment etc look bad, so this shows you were at least doing something.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with listing it as anything other than work experience, because it is work experience.

On the *not getting paid* part, did your family provide you with food to eat and a roof over your head while working at the restaurant?

Even if that's not the case, is it really possible to volunteer for a for-profit organization? I honestly don't know the answer to that but I'm guessing you shouldn't even if you can, and even if you do, advertising it is revealing your past salary, which invites other considerations.

Comment: Agree that it should be considered work experience.  Evaluate what work was done.  Were they what would be considered work duties, in scope, responsibility and time-commitment that would be paid if non-family were performing it?